# django-rest-swagger double slash

Tags: django, rest, swagger

I'm having trouble with django-rest-swagger. I did everything (or I think I did) like in swagger documentation, but when I try to test API via "Try it out!" button, it sends request like this, with double slashes

> "GET /api//activity/ HTTP/1.1" 404 8388

my_app/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activity', ActivityViewSet)
router.register(r'diary', DiaryViewSet)
router.register(r'discipline', DisciplineViewSet)
router.register(r'ingredient', IngredientViewSet)
router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet)
router.register(r'mealtype', MealTypeViewSet)
router.register(r'meal', MealViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', get_swagger_view(title='API')),
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('diet_app.urls'))
]
```

[How it looks at swagger site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yZse.png)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem; it is an upstream issue for those of us who use Django 2.0. The core issue was in django rest framework versions 3.7.3 and earlier. Running following command should solves the problem

```
pip install --upgrade djangorestframework
```

If you care to see the github history, thank the people who thought through these following two tickets.

See this github ticket https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5686 (closed) and has been consolidated into
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5675